# Let the relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ be defined as follows: $x\sim y \Leftrightarrow x- \lfloor x \rfloor= y-\lfloor y \rfloor$

Tags: real-analysis, equivalence-relations

> Let the relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ be defined as follows:
> $x\sim y \Leftrightarrow x- \lfloor x \rfloor= y-\lfloor y \rfloor$
> Here $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is equal to the largest integer $n$ such that $n\le x$.

> (a) Let  $M=\{x\in\mathbb{Q} \mid 0\le x \lt 1\}$. Show that ${Q}/_{\sim}  \cong M$.

The obvious choice for me became that if I map $x \to x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.
But then how can I prove that this is a bijection?
Can anyone please help me understanding the process? I've tried a lot but the best that I could come up with is the mapping. Also I can't even see how the equivalence classes look like here.

Comment: Take any (positive) mixed number $w+\frac{m}{d}$ and ignore the whole number part $w$. The equivalence classes are those with the same remaining fraction in lowest terms, $\frac{m}{d}$. Negative mixed numbers are going to mess with this because they'll be in the equivalence class of $1- \frac{m}{d}$ instead.

Comment: Can you plot $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ for, say, $x \in [-1,1]$?  This should make it clear which points in $\Bbb{R}$ lie in each equivalence class...

Comment: If you are used to working with modular arithmetic, you can also convert them to equivalence classes defined by the remainder $\mod d$ after multiplying by $d$.